# Using first column of dictionary/table as index/key

Tags: python, dictionary, astropy

I am trying to use a `astropy.table` as a 2d array, but I want to use the first column as an index as well.

E.g., I already have table that looks like:

```
 a   b  c  d
'1t'  2  3  4
'5t'  6  7  8
'9t'  0  10 11
```

Such that 
`print table['b'] = 2,6,0`

What I want is to pick one element such that
`print table['b']['5t'] = 6`

Is there a way to do that other than using `table['b'][1] = 6`?

Comment: maybe.. `table['b'][table['a'].index('5t')] = 6`

Answer (score 1):

I show an alternative solution with this example:

```
from astropy.table import Table, Column
import numpy as np
t = Table([['4t', '5t', '6t'], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],[10, 20, 30]], names=('a', 'b','c'))
print (t)
```

Out:

```
 a   b   c 
--- --- ---
 4t 0.1  10
 5t 0.2  20
 6t 0.3  30
```

Set index and use loc:

```
t.add_index('a')
T=t.loc
print (T['4t']['b'])
```

Out:

```
0.1
```

Comment: gives this error >> ValueError: Cannot create TableLoc object with no indices

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!